# CUPS: duplex printing crops page (same results via lpr and system dialog)

Tags: printing, pdf

I've printed a PDF file one-sided as follows:

```
lpr -P Canon_MG5600_series -o sides=one-sided document.pdf
```

The result is as expected (see left side of the image bellow).

However, when trying to print the same file in duplex:

```
lpr -P Canon_MG5600_series -o sides=two-sided-long-edge document.pdf
```

The page gets cropped at the top (see right side of the image bellow).

[Printed documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL1eb.jpg)

Any ideas how to get it working properly?

EDIT1: Tried printing via system dialog with same results

Comment: It looks like you print a "Portrait" as "Landscape", try `-o orientation-requested=3 ` , it is "portrait orientation (no rotation)". Ref.: https://www.cups.org/doc/options.html#OPTIONS

Comment: @MatsK Thanks for the idea, but printing with `-o orientation-requested=3` didn't change anything. I've tried printing even with system dialog, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a driver-related issue. After installing official printer drivers from the manufacturer it started working.